# Scientometric/bibliometric data retrieval from a list of DOI

Tags: data-request, tool-request, research, extracting, bibliometrics

I am a conducting bibliometric analysis on small/midsize sets of academic papers (40-400), in a [longitudinal](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9008/term-for-data-that-compares-a-day-to-same-day-of-a-week-month-year-ago) study (repeated over time on the same dataset).  I am interest in retrieving data for each paper, in order of importance (to me):

1. year and number of citations (the essential ones, the others are not mandatory)
2. number of authors, number of non-self citations and journal name (ISO form for instance)

This could be performed by hand, using different sources (ResearcherID or Web of Science, Scopus, Google Scholar). Are there open bases or tools to retrieve such information from a set of [Digital Object Identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier) (DOI)? It would be a plus to retrieve the same set of data from these three main sources.

Comment: Are you asking for a tool/code to be written to get it from these sources or for an open data alternative to those sources?

Comment: Open data keeping track of history would be prefered. As I doubt it exists, tools to scrap from openly visible data is appreciated

Comment: Librarians do this sort of research all the time for papers that their institution produces.  I wouldn't be surprised if this sort of info were integrated into IR (Institutional Repository) software, or some of the [reference management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_reference_management_software) packages

Comment: This info may be present, in my instiitution in a diffuse form (report-like document), every 5 years. So the  longitudinal aspect is missing too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe the [rcrossref](https://github.com/ropensci/rcrossref) package for R is helpful. To find the number of citations, You can do things such as

```
library(rcrossref)

# returns list:
# pap <- cr_works(dois = "10.1371/journal.pone.0042793") 
# pap$data will be 28-column data frame.

cr_citation_count(doi = "10.1371/journal.pone.0042793")
```

Result:

```
                           doi count
1 10.1371/journal.pone.0042793    41
```

The API will only work for CrossRef DOIs.
This means that the only works that can be searched for must have been published with a member of the Crossref consortium of publishers.

If you are not familiar with R, then instead you can work with the [CrossRef REST API](https://github.com/CrossRef/rest-api-doc) directly.

Answer (score 1):

Other than CrossRef alone, [OpenCitations](https://opencitations.net/datasets) might be of help to you as well.